# Include external drive in Time Machine backup: compatible formats?

Tags: hard-drive, backup, time-machine, ssd

I want to also back up my external drive to another Time Machine drive, but when I want to stop Time Machine from excluding it, I can't, since it's not clickable:

[image: Time Machine Preferences Screenshot]

I know the problem is, that it has to be in another format (currently ExFAT). **But which formats are compatible and which are best?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this article](https://www.heise.de/news/Apples-Time-Machine-laeuft-endlich-mit-APFS-4799037.html), the external drive has to be either an **HFS+ drive or (since Big Sur) an APFS drive**!
I tested it with an external **"APFS encrypted" drive** and it **worked**. I was able to disable the exclusion in the settings and thereby back up the external drive to Time Machine!